# How to find the Path of the image from the img directory in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am trying to obtain the path for the image in the img directory.

```
           $keyString = $this->session->userdata('selected_comp_name');
           print($keyString);
           $imageSrcPath = glob('/img/$keyString.{jpeg,gif,png}',GLOB_BRACE);
```

Here in the above code I am trying to get the company name from session and then I am trying to find the image from the img directory, which has the same name as the company nae but it could have an extension of png,jpeg, or gif. After getting the path I will display it with the img tag. But I am not able to get the path here, I am just getting a blank array.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My directory structure is www.sitename.com/img/therequiredimage.gif

Comment: Doesn't `glob()` return an array of found object(s) with their path(s)?

Comment: Yes and I think i should get the path of the required image with above code. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: I provided a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only three strings of code, I can't see any problems in them. But possible problems could arise if the `glob()` would return an absolute path of the image (say, `/usr/local/www/…/img/therequiredimage.gif`) and you couldn't use id with your `img` tag.

The easiest way in that case would be:

```
$imageSrcPath = glob('/img/$keyString.{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);

if(is_array($imageSrcPath) && isset($imageSrcPath[0])) $imgTag = '<img src="/img/'. basename($imageSrcPath[0]) .'"/>';
```